# Infix calculator

Tags: c, stack, infix-notation

Im writting a program (this is homework) to create an infix calculator in C using stacks. i came up with the following logic :

have two stacks : one for numbers , one for operators.

store input as a char string and then scan one char at a time , pushing each element into its proper stack.

ignore open parens , on encountering a closed paren : pop two numbers from numstack , and one operator from the opstack , calculate based on the popped values , and return the the answer.

example : `(1+(2*3))` should give 7

but its not working.
im getting garbage as output. 
this is my output :

```
enter string to be evaluated (100 chars max): (1+1)

string : (1+1)
Length : 5
 reading : (
 reading : 1  pushing : 1
 reading : +  pushing : 43
 reading : 1  pushing : 1
 reading : )  popping : 1 popping : 1 popping : 431 + 302 = 303
 pushing : 303
```

i dont understand why. some help would be great.

---

my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> // i **have to** use turbo c.
#define LEN 25

void push(int *stack  , int* top ,int item){
    printf(" pushing : %d ", item);
    stack[*top] = item;
    (*top)++;
}

int pop(int *stack , int* top){
    int temp;
    (*top)--;
    temp = stack[*top];
    printf(" popping : %d",temp); // this causing a dilemma while popping character operators.
    return temp;
}

void calc(int* numstack , int* numtop, int* opstack , int* optop){
    int num1,num2,ans;
    char sign;

    num1 = pop(numstack,numtop);
    num1 = pop(numstack,numtop);

    switch(pop(opstack,optop)){
        case '+' : ans = num1 + num2; sign = '+' ; break;
        case '-' : ans = num1 - num2; sign = '-' ; break;
        case '*' : ans = num1 * num2; sign = '*' ; break;
        case '/' : ans = num1 / num2; sign = '/' ; break;
    }
    printf("%d %c %d = %d \n",num1,sign,num2,ans);
    push(numstack,numtop,ans);
    while(getchar()!='\n'){} // cleanup stdin from any junk
}

int main(void){
    int optop = 0 , numtop = 0, i=0 , numstack[50] , opstack[30];
    char str[102], c;
    clrscr();

    // read and trim input evaluatioon string
    printf("enter string to be evaluated (100 chars max): ");
    fgets(str , 100 , stdin);
    while(str[i]!='\n'){ i++; }
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("\nstring : %s \nLength : %d",str,i);

    i = 0;
    // evaluate
    while( (c=str[i]) !='\0'){
    printf("\n reading : %c ",str[i]);
    if(c=='('){ i++; continue; } // ignore open parens
    else if(c=='+'||c=='-'||c=='*'||c=='/') push(opstack,&optop,c);
    else if(c>=48 && c <=57) push(numstack,&numtop,(c-48));
    else if(c==')') calc(numstack , &numtop, opstack , &optop);
    else printf("\n%c is invalid..\n",c);
    i++;
    }
    printf("\nanswer is : %g",pop(numstack,&numtop));
    getch(); // again , *must use* turbo c
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry .. the post button got pressed before i wanted. updated the query.

Comment: Look up reverse polish notation - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation. There is algorithms to convert to it from infix notation

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where the garbage is coming from?

Comment: Ugh, hardcoding `48` and `57`. Please use `c >= '0' && c < '9'`.

Comment: no. I dont know how to. i thought it would be a simple bug that im overlooking so i posted here.

Comment: When I try compiling your code I get: _calc.c:58: warning: format '%g' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'_

Comment: thanks barmar. apparantly turbo c isn't showing that error. more reasons not to like it.. ( still i'm stuck with it.) i'll try out what you said.

Comment: edited my code to include a output for a simple case.

Comment: Minor: to read 100 char + \n + \0: `fgets(str , sizeof(str) , stdin);`  `(c>='0' && c <='9')` is more meaningful and portable.

Comment: Ignoring open parens is clearly wrong, as `1*(2+3)` and `(1*2+3)` will be parsed the same way. There's an extensive literature on how to parse expressions using an operator stack and an operand stack ... you should look into it. Note that your example `(1+(2*3))` doesn't need parens at all, making it a very poor example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
num1 = pop(numstack,numtop);
num1 = pop(numstack,numtop);
```

You're assigning to `num1` both times, the first one should be `num2`.

You also need to change the the final answer line to:

```
printf("\nanswer is : %d\n",pop(numstack,&numtop));
```

`%g` is for doubles, `%d` is for ints.

Comment: great eyes ! thanks a lot. completely missed it. Also , I'd like to mention here that unlike modern compilers , turbo c doesnt give any errors for %d-%g mismatch. seems like it simply doesnt execute that line of code ( the printf in my case) . just felt i'd let people know.

Comment: It was pretty clear from the fact that it said one number in `popping:` and another number when it printed the calculation.

Comment: @SomjitNag It's not so much great eyes as experience, the way chess players look at a board and see a position whereas non chess players look at a board and see a jumble of pieces.

Comment: It didn't stick out to me, I had to run the program a few times and look at the output to see what didn't make sense, then work my way back from there. I saw that it printed `popping : 1 popping: 3` but then wrote `1 + 302 = 303`. So I wondered why `num2` was set to 303 when it should have been 3, worked my way back, and that's when I saw it.